# Oops! I said the B'Ymei Matisyahu instead of B'Ymei Mordechai

Tags: halacha, purim, mistakes, al-hanissim

Per [Orach Chaim 693:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=317) if one forgot Al Hanisim by Davening there is no need to repray. What if I said Al Hanisim, however I said the Chanuka version on Purim - do I have to Daven again or not? (sources)

Comment: Do you have any reason to assume this would be different than saying Yaaleh VeYavo for Shmini Atzeret on Purim?

Comment: It seems to be a machloket achronim. See the end of OC 108

Comment: @DoubleAA: So it seems like I got a question

Comment: Yes, but it seems like your question is overly specific.

Comment: @DoubleAA: This happened to a fellow in Shul on Purim when the Rav was not there and no one seemed to know what he should do. Hence the question.

Comment: Does he live in a walled city?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't see over-specificity here. There's no reason for the question to assume that the rule here is different from or the same as other prayers, or to discuss other prayers. An answer, of course, could relate this particular case to a larger class that it's part of.

Comment: Presumably, the question of שח בתפילה applies to the *bimei Matisyahu/bimei Mord'chai* section just as it applies to *ya'aleh v'yavo*. (Independent of that, however, it is possible that the first part of *al hanissim* serves some function even without the day-specific part, depending on the [function of *al hanissim*](http://www.yutorah.org/_shiurim/The%20Recitation%20of%20Al%20HaNissim.html). In general, though, I'm not sure if there would be a nafka mina in a case where someone said only the beginning part and forgot the rest.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rivevos Ephraim 1:457 brings the tzaddim of both sides,he ends off that one does not go back.
Rav Shmuel Kamentsky in Kovetz Halachos 7:5 holds one is yotzei and doesn't go back.The tzad that says that chanukka has a little bit of the same inyun since it is a praise for a nes.

Comment: Is your last sentence based on R Kamentsky? I don't see it in [Rivevos Ephraim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1081&st=&pgnum=370).

Comment: Yes in his footnotes